# In Django how to populate a form dropdown list form a column in a database

Tags: django

I am new to Django and python. I am attempting to populate a field in a custom user creation form with values in a separate table/column the database. Those values are created via another app and model (the Django Machina forum app).

So far I have not been able to figure out how to even import the model to gain access to the values.

My models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    business_location_state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm



class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('username', 'email', 'age', 'business_location_state')





class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'age',)
```

signup.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
  Sign Up
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

The Machina github is found here: https://github.com/ellmetha/django-machina

Any ideas about how to use values in the table forum_forum and column "id" as a dropdown in the field business_location_state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a foreign key pointing out to the Forum table in Machina.

If that is the case, then you should define the `business_location_state` field as a [models.ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

This ForeignKey should be pointing out to the Forum model. If you look at Machina source code you can see [how they access this model](https://github.com/ellmetha/django-machina/blob/d60dfb3a72e234c7823f69a7f0f46224af8604c7/machina/apps/forum/admin.py#L28) and replicate it.

```
from machina.core.db.models import get_model

Forum = get_model("forum", "Forum")

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    business_location_state = models.ForeignKey(Forum, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: How would you add the equivalent of a WHERE clause for filtering?

Comment: I found the answer: use limit_choices_to. For example: business_location_state = models.ForeignKey(Forum, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, limit_choices_to={"column_name":value})